# Textbook for partial differential equations with the tools of complex analysis

Tags: reference-request, partial-differential-equations

Is there a textbook in partial differential equations that has a lot of solved excercises by using complex analysis tools?

Answer (score 0):

I've been teaching PDEs (both undergraduate and graduate) for years and I do not even know many such exercises which could be solved using Complex Analysis tools - Unless we are referring to Fourier series or Fourier transform.